# Associate AWS CDK EmailConfigurationProperty with UserPool

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

How do I associate EmailConfigurationProperty with UserPool? I have both objects configured, but do not see the path to connect them.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cognito.UserPool.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cognito.CfnUserPool.EmailConfigurationProperty.html

```
public class CdkStackMain extends Stack {

    public CdkStackMain(final Construct scope, final String id, final StackProps props, StackMode stackMode) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        // other objects created here

        UserPool userPool = UserPool.Builder.create(this, myAppName+"-UserPoolv008")
                .userPoolName(myAppName)
                .autoVerify(autoVerifiedAttrs)
                .accountRecovery(AccountRecovery.EMAIL_AND_PHONE_WITHOUT_MFA)
                .selfSignUpEnabled(true)
                .passwordPolicy(passwordPolicy)
                .signInCaseSensitive(false)
                .standardAttributes(standardAtts)
                .signInAliases(signinAliases)
                .build();

        EmailConfigurationProperty emailConfigurationProperty = EmailConfigurationProperty.builder()
                .sourceArn("arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:000000000:identity/my-id")
                .from("Some Name <somename@company.com>")
                .replyToEmailAddress("Some Name <somename@company.com>")
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: AWS CDK supports many languages, so having 'Java' in the title was helpful, because the solutions in Python or TypeScript are different from the solution in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of AWS CDK v1.62.0 the UserPool high level object does not have a setter for the EmailConfigurationProperty. The solution is to use the setter on the CfnUserPool low level object.

```
UserPool userPool = UserPool.Builder.create(this, myAppName+"-UserPoolv010")
    .userPoolName(myAppName)
    .autoVerify(autoVerifiedAttrs)
    .accountRecovery(AccountRecovery.EMAIL_AND_PHONE_WITHOUT_MFA)
    .selfSignUpEnabled(true)
    .passwordPolicy(passwordPolicy)
    .signInCaseSensitive(false)
    .standardAttributes(standardAtts)
    .signInAliases(signinAliases)
    .lambdaTriggers(userPoolTriggers)
    .build();

EmailConfigurationProperty emailConfigurationProperty = EmailConfigurationProperty.builder()
    .emailSendingAccount(EmailSendingAccountType.DEVELOPER.toString())
    .sourceArn("arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:0000000:identity/customer_support@company.com")
    .from("customer_support@company.com")
    .replyToEmailAddress("customer_support@company.com")
    .build();

CfnUserPool cfnUserPool = (CfnUserPool)userPool.getNode().getDefaultChild();
cfnUserPool.setEmailConfiguration(emailConfigurationProperty);
```